# Scaling a UIBezier to fit a UIView (Swift)

Tags: uiview, swift, uibezierpath

Any suggestion on how to have a UIBezierPath scale to fit a static sized UIView. The kicker is this could potentially be scaled down considerably so it would be nice if my line widths maintained their width. The code below actually requires the Bezier to be scaled up... This is not going to be the usual case and will usually be scaled down and scaled down a lot, potentially 100 times or more.

```
class myView:UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
        myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 10))
        myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 55, y: 100))
        myBezier.closePath()
        myBezier.lineWidth = 4
        UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
        myBezier.stroke()
        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        myBezier.fill()
    }
}

var view = myView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 200))
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

[image]

Comment: When you say scaled down by 100 times, yet maintain line width, do you mean the dimensions reduce from 0-100 to 0-1 but the line width remains 4? Or line width reduce to 0.04?

Comment: Line width remains at 4... a line at 0.04 would be extremely hard to see!

Comment: Line width of 4 with triangle dimension <1 will be - um - not very triangle-y? I take it you don't want to just recreate the path with scaled coordinates?

Comment: Really I'm open to accomplishing this any number of ways. The Bezier paths will generally be pretty simple polygons but could be large or could have an origin far away from (0,0) that would put it off the screen. The ultimate goal is to be able to graph these polygons on a coordinate plane.